# Getting null object reference while doing web checkout in android

Tags: android, shopify

I am trying to implement simple e-commerce application by using android buy sdk. Fetching products and collections working fine. But when i do the web checkout getting null object reference.Here i am passing variant id and quantities. I am following this  [link](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android#fetch-collections-and-products-).

```
Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput input = new Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput()
  .setLineItemsInput(Input.value(Arrays.asList(
    new Storefront.CheckoutLineItemInput(new ID("mFyaWFu"), 5),
    new Storefront.CheckoutLineItemInput(new ID("8vc2hGl"), 3)
  )));
Storefront.MutationQuery query = Storefront.mutation(mutationQuery -> mutationQuery
                           .checkoutCreate(input, createPayloadQuery -> createPayloadQuery
                                   .checkout(checkoutQuery -> checkoutQuery.webUrl())
                                   .userErrors(userErrorQuery -> userErrorQuery
                                           .field()
                                           .message()
                                   )
                           )
                   );
                   Log.d(TAG,"Mutation Query :::"+query.toString());
                   graphClient.mutateGraph(query).enqueue(new GraphCall.Callback<Storefront.Mutation>() {
                       @Override public void onResponse(@NonNull GraphResponse<Storefront.Mutation> response) {
                          if(!response.data().getCheckoutCreate().getUserErrors().isEmpty()){
                              for(Storefront.UserError error : response.data().getCheckoutCreate().getUserErrors()){
                                  Log.d(TAG,"Error :::"+error.getMessage());
                              }
                          }else {
                              String checkoutUrl = response.data().getCheckoutCreate().getCheckout().getWebUrl();
                              Log.d(TAG,"Url :::"+checkoutUrl);
                          }

                       }

                       @Override public void onFailure(@NonNull GraphError error) {
                           // handle errors
                           Log.d(TAG,"Error ::"+error.getMessage());
                       }
                   });
```

I am getting below error when do the checkout

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.shopify.buy3.Storefront$CheckoutCreatePayload.getUserErrors()' on a null object reference
        at com.myhealth.iris.welcome.View.fragments.shopCart.CartItemsActivity$1$1.onResponse(CartItemsActivity.java:127)
        at com.shopify.buy3.RealGraphCall$CallbackProxy.onResponse(RealGraphCall.java:239)
        at com.shopify.buy3.HttpCallbackWithRetry.lambda$notifyResponse$0$HttpCallbackWithRetry(HttpCallbackWithRetry.java:110)
        at com.shopify.buy3.-$$Lambda$HttpCallbackWithRetry$W122BeJY-i5AKeY0PiirJ1C6YLo.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.shopify.buy3.HttpCallbackWithRetry.notifyResponse(HttpCallbackWithRetry.java:114)
        at com.shopify.buy3.HttpCallbackWithRetry.onResponse(HttpCallbackWithRetry.java:88)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Please can any one guide me how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```response.data()``` may be null. Check it

Comment: When i trying to print the response data getting like this com.shopify.buy3.Storefront$Mutation@f8e41ef